# Updating DB-How do I fix "ViewModel is not part of the model for the current context"

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, post, viewmodel

I created a view model and associated controller and view, but it looks like there's a piece missing in both my head and my code. When I submit the page, with or without DB changes, I get the following. "The entity type ReportReviewViewModel is not part of the model for the current context."

Models (not all fields)

```
public partial class RFDS
{
    public System.Guid rfds_processing_id { get; set; }
    public string location_name { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
}

public partial class Sub_Clients_Xref
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string sub_client { get; set; }
    public string sub_client_attn { get; set; }
    public string sub_client_address { get; set; }
}

public partial class Engineering_License_Xref
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string state_name { get; set; }
    public string license_number { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel

```
public class ReportReviewViewModel
{
    public RFDS rfds { get; set; }
    public Sub_Clients_Xref subclient { get; set; }
    public Engineering_License_Xref engineer { get; set; }
    public States_Xref state { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Review(Guid? id)
{
if (id == null)
{
    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
}

RFDS rfds_db = db.RFDS.Find(id);
if (rfds_db == null)
{
    return HttpNotFound();
}

List<RFDS> rfds1 = db.RFDS.ToList();
List<Sub_Clients_Xref> subclients = db.Sub_Clients_Xref.ToList();
List<Engineering_License_Xref> engineers = db.Engineering_License_Xref.ToList();
List<States_Xref> states = db.States_Xref.ToList();


var viewModel = (from r in rfds1
    join s in subclients on r.sub_client equals s.sub_client
    join st in states on r.state equals st.state
    join e in engineers on r.engineer_name equals e.engineer_name
    where r.rfds_processing_id == id && r.sub_client == s.sub_client && 
(r.engineer_name == e.engineer_name && e.state_name == st.state_name)
    select new ReportReviewViewModel
    {
        rfds = r,
        subclient = s,
        engineer = e
    });
return View(viewModel);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Review(ReportReviewViewModel viewModel)
{

if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    db.Entry(viewModel).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Review");
}

return View(viewModel);
}
```

`UPDATED CONTROLLER`

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Review(ReportReviewViewModel viewModel)
    {
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    db.Entry(viewModel.rfds).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.Entry(viewModel.engineer).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.Entry(viewModel.subclient).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.Entry(viewModel.state).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Review");
 }
```

`VIEW example`

```
@model IEnumerable<TeamWeb.ViewModels.ReportReviewViewModel>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Review";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<div class="container2">
<div class="nav col-md-3">
    @Html.ActionLink("BACK TO LIST", "Index")
</div>
<hr />
<table class="rev-table-main" border="0">

    <!----------------------------- EDIT DATA ----------------------------->
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Review", "RFDS", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()            
        foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => item.rfds.rfds_processing_id)
            <tr>
                <td class="rev-values-td">
                    <table class="rev-table-values" border="0">
                        @*<tr class="rev-tr">
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>*@
                        <tr class="rev-tr">
                            <td style="font-size:medium;font-weight:600;text-align:center;" colspan="2">
                                Edit Report Information
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align:right;" width="40%">
                                Site Name:
                            </td>
                            <td width="60%">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => item.rfds.location_name)

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right">
                                FA Location Code:
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => item.rfds.fa_location_code)
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right">
                                Site Address:
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => item.rfds.address)
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right">
                                Site City:
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => item.rfds.city)
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right">
                                Site State:
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => item.rfds.state)
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right">
                                Site Zip Code:
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => item.rfds.zip_code)
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2">
                                <hr />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right">
                                Sub Client:
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => item.subclient.sub_client)
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right">
                                Sub Client Attn:
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => item.subclient.sub_client_attn)
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right">
                                Sub Client Address:
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => item.subclient.sub_client_address)
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right">
                                Sub Client City:
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => item.subclient.sub_client_city)
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right">
                                Sub Client State:
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => item.subclient.sub_client_state)
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right">
                                Sub Client Zip Code:
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => item.subclient.sub_client_zip)
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2">
                                <hr />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right">
                                Capability %:
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => item.rfds.capability)
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2">
                                <hr />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right">
                                Report Date:
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => item.rfds.submit_date)
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right">
                                Job Number:
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => item.rfds.job_number)
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right">
                                Revision:
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => item.rfds.revision)
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2">
                                &nbsp;
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2" align="center">
                                <input type="submit" value="Save" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
             </tr>
           }
         }
       </table>
</div>
```

Comment: `db.Entry(viewModel)` - this is not allowed (exception). Only entity models can be attached/added/updated/deleted through db context. Probably you need `db.Entry(viewModel.rfds).State = EntityState.Modified;` And similar for other view model properties.

Comment: I updated my controller as suggested. I'm getting an error because the value for all 4  view models is null.

Comment: I've tried everything I can think of but continue to get null values for each property. In the debugger I'm seeing a single null for each viewModel property. Shouldn't I be seeing a list of all the items in each model?  `db.Entry(viewModel.rfds).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.Entry(viewModel.engineer).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.Entry(viewModel.subclient).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.Entry(viewModel.state).State = EntityState.Modified;`

Comment: EF part ends here. Apparently you have issues with passing data between view and controller, hence I would suggest removing the EF tag and adding the appropriate tags, so the people with experience in that area could eventually help you.